# Problem with Manifest V3: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Promise]" is not valid JSON

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Been trying to move my extension to Manifest V3.
Hit a roadblock early on.

Hit with 2 error as I try to adapt to the new service worker style.

- Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Promise]" is not valid JSON

I suppose since the registration failed, I can't call the "inspect view" link so I can't console.log stuff.
At a loss of how to debug the problem.

Here is a very simplified version that produce the errors.

https://www.sendspace.com/file/3km5n8

Comment: You need to put the code in the question, not in an external link. There are several problems in your code, the main one is that chrome.storage methods return a Promise so you need to `await` it inside an `async` function.

Comment: Actually I don't know what code to put in the question as the second error didn't point to any meaningful line. Hmm, will check on the chrome.storage Promise stuff. Promise, another thing about this newer JS stuff I don't get.